# Should I use "this is" or "that is" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> If I lie to you, I'll lose your trust forever. **This** is the last thing I want.
>
> If I lie to you, I'll lose your trust forever. **That's** the last
> thing I want.

What's the most appropriate option? Or maybe they are both correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That* is much more likely than *this*.

The reason has little to do with whether it is near or far, as suggested by Joshua.

When we are referring to objects or places that are physically present, we do indeed prefer *this* for closer objects.

But when we are talking of things that have only been referred to linguistically, we usually use *that*, especially in ordinary speech. Using *this* sounds stilted, unless we are setting up an opposition between the statement or reference we are referring to and some other statement or reference.

Your first example with *this* suggests that you are going to go on and say some alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think "that" is the most appropriate thing to say.

My reasoning:

1. You are supposed to say "this" when something is close. So if something bad has happened, you should say "I did not want this to happen."
2. You are supposed to say "that" when something is distant. So if something bad hasn't happened *yet*, you should say "I do not want that to happen."

Look at what you said:

"If I lie to you, I'll lose your trust forever."

They haven't lied *yet*, which means that "that" is most appropriate.