# Should we use "this" or "that" here

Tags: phrases, pronouns, formal-language

> I feel a little sick. That/This is why I'm going home early.

Should we use "that" or "this" here? Or are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. "That is why" and "This is why" is mostly interchangeable. "This is why" is preferred when it is about a proximate observable event, e.g. There is a banana peel on the road and a person is walking towards it and you say, "Look" and after a moment the person slips on the banana peel, and you say to your companion, "This is why I do not step on banana peels": or the chemistry would say to you "This is why you have to do the experiment this way.".

Comment: "chemistry teacher" @"chemistry". Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Just in terms of grammar, "that" can always replace "this", though the meaning usually changes. Are you asking about whether they have the same meaning or whether they're natural, or just about whether they're grammatical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use "this is" or "that is" in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266707/should-i-use-this-is-or-that-is-in-the-following-sentence) As pointed out by the answer there, we *tend* to use ***this*** for nearby *physical* things, and ***that*** for "lexical references" to more "abstract" targets such as *reasons expressed in words*.